# Why is there no foot tag in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, w3c

We have a `head` tag and a `body` tag. For the `body` tag we now have `header`, `main`, and `footer` tags.

Why is there no `foot` tag to correlate to the `head` and `body` tag?

This `foot` tag would be perfect for people to place JavaScript code that needs to be loaded at the end of a page; as people frequently do this but have to place their JS within the `body` tag. I am under the impression that JS code within the `body` tag is technically out of spec, since it doesn't actually provide anything that contributes to the body of the document directly. A `foot` tag would effectively function just like the `head` tag (not actually display anything within the document body), but be placed after the closing `body` tag.

Am I missing something here, or is this something that has just not been thought of?

Comment: You're overthinking things. A script in the body is not technically out of spec.

Comment: There is no need for the foot tag. Because You don't necessarily need to put script in body, you can put it in the head. If you need your JavaScript to run after html is loaded put the script in head and use DOMContentLoaded event. If you don't want your script in head delay the rendering of html, just defer the script. Problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

Since an HTML page is typically rendered top-down, having a  tag at the bottom of the page would basically just by syntactic sugar over adding something to the bottom of the body of a page.

The `<head>` tag has a special purpose in that browsers and crawlers can parse just this tag to get metadata about a website without needing to look at the full HTML, but the `<foot>` tag would have no such benefit, meaning it would be a useless tag for browsers to support, when people could really just add whatever they need to the bottom of the body to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I could actually see this being useful for browsers.  You could put your script tags in the `foot` so the browser could do a pre-fetch of the JS files that are then executed after the `body` is loaded to help reduce load times.

Comment: if you want to pre-fetch the scripts then they should be at the top. if you want them to be fetched after the body is loaded then put the scripts tag just before the closing </body>.